# Mysql ODBC connector not available in stamps.com datasource

Tags: mysql, odbc, 64-bit, stamps.com

Today, we upgraded stamps.com software to version 17.5. This build requires that ODBC drivers be 64bit. I didn't think that was a problem. System is 64bit, and downloaded the latest MySQL ODBC 64Bit version 8.0.22. ODBC Data Source Administrator loads up, and I can access it. I create the datas ource (tested) but when I try to assign it via Stamps.com I get the error...

```
"Unable to connect to the selected data source. Check if you need to add a Username and Password"
```

Odd. Again, I can test connection via ODBC Data Source Administrator. It selects the proper database, etc. The driver is MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver (Version 8.00.22.00).

If I try to "Create a new data source" via Stamps.com. Click 'Other/Advanced (SQL,etc)' and click 'Add', I do not see any MySQL drivers anywhere the options.

I've completely uninstalled re-installed 8.0.22 multiple times.

### ADDITIONAL INFO

If I don't try to create a new DSN through Stamps.com but rather select an existing one, but click 'configure'. I get the following errors.

```
"The setup routines for the MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver ODBC driver could not be found.  Please reinstall the driver."
```

Followed by..

```
"---------------------------
Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed
---------------------------
Errors Found:

The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"
```

So it seems like the MySQL ODBC driver is still 32 bit? I clearly installed 64 bit, and the system is 64 bit, so not sure. It's possible the original ODBC driver was 32 bit from a year ago, but like I mentioned, I have removed those .dll via uninstall.

### ADDITIONAL INFO 2

I'm wondering if I'm chasing the wrong 32 bit application. Under ODBC Data Source Administrator, in the About tab,

For About the ODBC core components..

```
Administrator C:\Windows\system32\odbccp32.dll
Control Panel Startup C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe
Cursor Library C:\Windows\system32\odbccr32.dll
Driver Manager C:\Windows\system32\odbc32.dll
Localized Resource DLL C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
Unicode Cursor Library C:\Windows\system32\odbccu32.dll
```

So it looks like the 'core' for ODBC is 32 bit? Looking into how to update these for 64bit. Hmmm... based on my initial research, those .dll/.exe are 64bit since they're in system32 and not in sysWOW64. Seems counter intuitive?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay.. today I received a message requiring 17.7 for international rates. Unfortunately, their download page shows 64bit and 32bit downloads.. but their site sucks. Only stamps64.exe is ever downloaded. 64 bit 17.7 is still not compatible with 64 bit ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting support, they informed me that ODBC is not supported with 17.5. So not sure - why I needed to upgrade to 64bit, and why it states that my ODBC drivers need to be 64bit, since it's not compatible.

Here is what needs to be done. Download Stamps clean tool:
https://support.stamps.com/outgoing/clean.exe

Then run key tool to remove any registry values:
https://support.stamps.com/outgoing/key.exe

Then finally, you need to install version 17.4
http://support.stamps.com/outgoing/stamps174.exe

Roll back to the 32bit ODBC drivers.

After this fiasco, we've implemented better protocols. Basically secondary machine with Stamps.com running on it and will test future updates there before rolling out to our primary production machine.

Answer (score 0):

We are in the same boat.... after updating to the Stamps.com version 17.5 we have been unable to get our ODBC MySQL server connection working.
We have tried all combinations of older vs new 64 bit MySQL drivers. We have tried installing the 32-bit version of Stamps 17.5. It actually allows us to configure the connection and select the correct tables and columns we want, but when we trigger a lookup we get an error saying 64bit drivers are required.

Same error on 32-bit Stamps.com vs 64-bit Stamps.com.
We are contacting stamps.com support now and I will update this when/if we find anything additional.

Comment: It's a nightmare. You need to run the cleaner tool, key tool and install 17.4. Here is the catch after contacting them.. they said that no ODBC drivers are compat with 64 bit stamps. WTF?

Comment: Answered below.

Comment: And now we NEED to update to 17.7. Problem still persists, with the 64bit ODBC driver issue. Don't get it since mapping is complete, etc. Just fails on order import.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a solution then for this?  We were actually using for the past 12 years the old ActiveX solution - but you HAD to use MS-Explorer.  So we were exploring using stamps.com ORDERS solution with MySQL ODBC.  Tried both the 32-bit stamps.com app (with the 32bit ODBC drivers), and the 64-bit stamps.com (with the 64bit ODBC drivers).  The 32-bit at least allow you to complete the field mapping - which tells me it was connected to the database to be able to read the schema.  But when you go to actually IMPORT anything, you get the "...you'll need to install the latest 64-bit ODBC drivers..." which I have already tried.

If you download and use the 17.4 version (as suggested above), what happens when you MUST upgrade stamps.com (which does happen about once every 2 years when the USPS changes some fundamental stuff).

Any solutions anyone?  We really want off our ActiveX/PDK (12 year old) solution.

Comment: I didn't say this.. but you need to roll back to 32bit ODBC driver if you're running 17.4

Comment: And here we are.. 3 months later, and we NEED to update to 17.7. Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue this week, albeit with the MS SQL drivers. Doesn't matter whether I install the 64bit or 32bit Stamps.com software (when the site will download the 32bit version at all... it doesn't for me at the moment, only 64bit). Either way, I get the message saying I need to install the 64bit ODBC drivers. And clicking "More info" just takes me to the home Help page, *not* to a related article. The article detailing 64bit ODBC is pretty useless since it just says you need to install the drivers, but you can view it here: https://stamps.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7244/kw/64-bit%20ODBC/related/1

I called support, and they said it's a known issue but that there's no workaround currently.

**UPDATE 2/17/2021**
I just talked to Tier 2 support, and there's a new version out the resolves the ODBC error. The download page still says 17.7, but it's actually 17.7.1. Installing it resolved the error for me and I am now able to import orders via ODBC. (I installed the 32-bit version at the recommendation of the support tech I spoke with, I have not tried with the 64-bit version.)

Also, the 32-bit download is working again.

Comment: I was thinking that I was the only one dealing with this. I called support as well, and they said the 32bit version of stamps.exe was suppose to address this. I told them it doesn't and they would call back. I contacted support on Tuesday 2/2. Still haven't heard back.

Comment: I still haven't heard back from Stamps support, and just sent another email. Any word on your end?

Comment: Nope, I've contacted them via the contact form and via their support email since I last talked to them on the phone, and still no further response.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for letting me know. Will try on our end. Did you have to re-do the database mapping? Or was the update clean?

Comment: Thanks again @JGlick 17.7.1 installed. Clean migration with mapping. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Version 18.0 is now available. ODBC seems to work in the 32 bit version, I have not tried the 64 bit version.
Thanks to all who persisted in contacting stamps.com.