# stamps.com software 17.7 version mysql ODBC connector import order has error

Tags: mysql, import, odbc, stamps.com

We are trying to setup mysql ODBC connector on stamps.com version 17.7 to import order from mysql database and postback data to mysql database.
We added new mysql data source without issue.
But got below error message dialog when we tried to import oder from the configed data source.
"In order to proceed with order import, you'll need to install the latest 64-bit ODBC drivers. Click More Info... to learn how to install these drivers."

This error message also shows up when trying to edit the mysql data source.
Any one got same issue and have any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This has been an ongoing problem since 17.5, and it appears to affect pretty much every DB. I don't use mysql, but our database has a 64 bit ODBC driver and gets the same error. There is no workaround except reverting to 17.4, and right now doing so means you won't be able to do international shipments.

Here's another thread on the subject: [Mysql ODBC connector not available in stamps.com datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564719/mysql-odbc-connector-not-available-in-stamps-com-datasource)